# Typings for braintree.dropin v3 typings for angular

Tags: braintree, typescript-typings

I'm integrating Braintree Drop-in v3 into an angular app with package
`npm i -save braintree-web-drop-in`.

Then I found package `@types/braintree-web` I was following the example mentioned [here](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in) however it doesn't seem to contain support for Drop-in functionality. Clearly this is not the right package.

```
braintree.dropin.create({
  authorization: environment.braintreeKey,
  selector: '#dropin-container'
}, function (err, dropinInstance) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle any errors that might've occurred when creating Drop-in
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    dropinInstance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle errors in requesting payment method
      }

      // Send payload.nonce to your server
    });
  });
});
```

I have import statement 
`import * as braintree from "@types/braintree-web";`

Then `braintree` gets recognized as a global namespace, however `braintree.dropin` is still causing me problems.

The Typescript compiler is complaining about dropin object:

`Property 'dropin' does not exist on type 'typeof braintree'.`

Question:

Is there some easy way to tell typescript it's all fine and roll with it? Or do I have to provide typings myself? Or do they exist somewhere already? Or it would be better to use braintree-web-package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by using `import * as dropin from 'braintree-web-drop-in';` Its possible because I have braintree module installed in `node_modules`

Its clearly the Typescript basics, but nerveless something I didn't knew about.

Since this question is about braintree drop in UI, here is my code combined with Typescript and angular 2. Javascript treats `this` differently than Typescript, so you shouldn't use `function` keyword inside Typescript.

```
  braintreeIsReady: boolean;
  dropIninstance: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    dropin.create({
      authorization: environment.braintreeKey,
      selector: '#dropin-container'
    }, (err, dropinInstance) => {
      if (err) {
        // Handle any errors that might've occurred when creating Drop-in
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      this.dropIninstance = dropinInstance;
      this.braintreeIsReady = true;
    });
  }

  pay() {
    this.dropIninstance.requestPaymentMethod((err, payload) => {
      if (err) {
        // deal with error
      }
      else {
        //send nonce to the server

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Been stuck on integration from 2 days...Thanks a lot !